# Mongo: $addToSet on object array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my app a review of a route can be liked, but also unliked. How do I insert a particular ID in the likes array (reviews.$.likes) and how do I remove a particular ID from the likes array?

```
route = {
    ...,
    reviews: [{
        text: "abc",
        userId: "1userId2",
        timestamp: 1497205637,
        likes: ["RKWSGJXbD7ayBLC9Q", "RC5JQR5RoHm58A2Fm"]
    }],
    ...
}
```

Based on the combination of the **userId** and the **timestamp** a review will be uniquely identified. So, I want to be able to remove a particular ID from likes by a given userId and timestamp.

Comment: The hierarchy is the same for every route as above, the other attributes are irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, understood! :)

Comment: Thanks for helping, do you understand the question? Anything I can clarify? @DakshShah

Comment: Are you using Mongoose along with MongoDB in your application?

Comment: @DakshShah, no, using it with MeteorJS and not validation schemes. I know its bad.

Comment: Okay, no problem.. I have no experience with MeteorJS but I'll try to answer this :)

Comment: @DakshShah thanks, that would be much appreciated

Comment: Add `.update({ "reviews": { "$elemMatch": { "text": "1userId2", "timestamp": 1497205637 } },{ "$addToSet": { "reviews.$.likes": "RKWSGJXbD7ayBLC9Q" }})` Remove: `.update({ "reviews": { "$elemMatch": { "text": "1userId2", "timestamp": 1497205637 } }, { "$pull": { "reviews.$.likes":  "RKWSGJXbD7ayBLC9Q" }})` Should be plenty of sources around to tell you to use `$elemMatch` to match an array element on multiple properties.